# Win8 Metro UI sidebar example?

Tags: windows-8, sidebar, microsoft-metro

Anyone knows where I can find sample code for Win8 Metro UI sidebars? Not the ones for win7 gadgets, but the one that's newly introduced for Win8.

This sidebar can be toggled when you try to setup your wifi or other settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question. If this is not cool, let me know. I will delete this answer.

I asked the [same question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/57b4bfc1-b39f-420f-9ec2-7dff5c3cd235) on MSDN, this "sidebar" is actually called "Setting Charm". Sample code can be found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-settings-sample-44ee1015).

An answer from [another post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/winappsuidesign/thread/042ba543-0d0f-47f6-8ad2-22f5805abd5b) indicates that you can NOT create your own Charm.

Comment: Just come back and accept the answer after the waiting period expires so that people searching will see it has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks to T.Rob and Tom van der Woerdt